# How add cells in UITableView on button click?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`.It has two custom prototype cells.Now one cell is fixed it will be just remain one in tableview but another cell will be added to tableview again & again on button click.

below is code for the tableview methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr_fields.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cellIndentifier="property"

        let cell:CreatePropertyCell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIndentifier, for: indexPath) as! CreatePropertyCell
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        cell.txt_propertyName.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Name of property",
                                                                         attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray])

        return cell

    } else {
        let cellIdentifier = "attribute"
        let cell:AddProperty=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddProperty
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        cell.txt_AddProperty.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Property Attribute",
                                                                        attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray])
        cell.btnAdd.tag=indexPath.row
        return cell

    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let header = UIView()
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return header

}

@IBAction func actionAddProperty(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let cellIdentifier = "attribute"
    let cell:AddProperty = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! AddProperty
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.txt_AddProperty.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Property Attribute",
                                                                    attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray])
    cell.tag=sender.tag!+1
    arr_fields.append(cell)
    tableView.reloadData()
    print("tag is \(sender.tag!)")
}
```

Now i just want to add second cell to the table view not the both the cells.As of now it adds both the cells to the table view.

Comment: why are you storing whole cell inside `arr_fields` array? How did you declare this array? What is its type?

Comment: Welll i have textfield & add button in array so on click of add button i want to add a new text field below current cell.So i thought i would create a new cell on button click & add it to array & reload the data

Comment: What is the datatype of arr_field array?

Comment: property cell  it is a custom cell

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return arr_fields.count
    }
}
```

Insert Cell: Rather than reloading Table, insert one cell into the Table:

```
@IBAction func actionAddProperty(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let cellIdentifier = "attribute"
    let cell:AddProperty = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! AddProperty
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.txt_AddProperty.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Property Attribute",
                                                                    attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray])
    cell.tag=sender.tag!+1

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forRow: arr_fields.count-1, inSection: 1)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    arr_fields.append(objComment)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Comment: let indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forRow: arr_fields.count-1, inSection: 1)
giving error as argument label for row in section do not match any available overloads.I am using swift 3

Comment: what about number of sections in tableview

Comment: You could have used IndexPath instead of NSIndexPath

Comment: In your source code, let change: `if section == 0 { return 1 } else { return arr_field.count }` and `tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: arr_fields.count - 1, section: 1)], with: .none)` instead of `tableView.reloadData()` as @Mr.Bista said

Comment: return 2 sections